# Using std::string in c++ for unmanaged c# dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, stl, wrapper

I'm trying to set up an unmanaged DLL package for c# for a c++ SDK that a client has provided. This SDK uses std::string and std::wstring variables. I found out that it's hard/impossible to use STL variables like string and wstring for this but it's kind of my last resort. I'm really hoping for someone that could tell me a possible way of building a c# dll wrapper for c++ methods that use std::string & std::wstring.

Comment: It is hard in C++, it can only work when you use the *exact* same C++ compiler with the *exact* same build settings.  Which only ever works in practice if you have source code or a highly disciplined software vendor that provides you with multiple builds.  It is impossible in C#, you cannot create/destroy/interpret these C++ template class objects.  You need a C++/CLI wrapper, be sure to work with the library vendor to get what you need.

Comment: I am working with the exact c++ compilers though so that is not the issue fortunately. But perhaps for future planning it might be a good idea to use the c++/cli.

Comment: Seems you missed the message, it is **required** to use C++/CLI.  There is no planning, the future is today.  And don't ignore the *exact same build settings* requirement, the difference between the Debug and Release build settings is already good enough to corrupt memory.

Comment: I know the build settings have to be the same but I'm sure that they are at this point. What I meant to say was that besides me being sure it's not the build settings at fault it would be a good idea to use C++/CLI instead of an unmanaged wrapper because I can't be sure that that will also be the case in the future.

Comment: Hans Passant, I think you're right though so you could possibly send your answer as an answer so I can mark it. Perhaps there is some way to achieve this but I don't think I'm on the right path, gonna try the C++/CLI approach. Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting `std::string` to `System::String^` as stated in [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235219.aspx)

Comment: I would like to do that but the SDK already uses methods that I can't alter that use the std::string